# Identify a movie from the 80s with a crystal mask and bleeding tree

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking to identify an 80s movie. It was kinda like Mad Max. All I can remember is the main character had a crystal mask, and when he put it on he was in front of a tree, which bled when he hit it with an axe. Then he pulled the mask off and he was returned to where he was before he put on the mask.

Comment: Teleportation or alternate dimension?

Comment: yes it seemed when he put the mask to his face he was in a different place alone he didnt have the mask and when he hit the tree it freaked him out. I was a kid when I saw it so I dont remember much but would like to rewatch it.

Comment: what do you mean "he was back" after pulling off the mask?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the movie - it is [**Metalstorm: The Destruction of Jared-Syn**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalstorm:_The_Destruction_of_Jared-Syn).

> The movie is a space-age western that portrays the story of a space
>   ranger named Dogen (played by Jeffrey Byron), who is in search of an
>   intergalactic criminal with supernatural powers named Jared-Syn
>   (played by Michael Preston).

And here's a screengrab of the crystal mask:

[image]

Comment: After looking this thing up, I gotta watch it now!

Comment: [Here's an image of the crystal mask](https://forgottenfilmcast.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/metalstorm-3.png), which may be useful to include in the answer for confirmation purposes, in case anyone in the future is searching for a movie with a crystal mask...